# How to set a environment variable in telnetd and access it in login

Tags: telnet

Given that

> telnetd operates by allocating a Telnet pseudo-terminal device for a
>   client, then creating a login process, which has the slave side of the
>   Telnet pseudo-terminal as stdin, stdout, and stderr. telnetd
>   manipulates the master side of the Telnet pseudo-terminal,
>   implementing the TELNET protocol, and passing characters between the
>   client and login process.

I am trying to get remote host's IP address and port number in login process, once telnet connection is established and user is authenticated.

In telnetd main() after getpeername succeeds I added setenv of REMOTE_HOST and REMOTE_PORT 
and trying to access these variables in login process. But Im not able to access these env vars in login.c.

My question is too specific but if anyone has already tried adding a env var in telnetd and able to access in login process, please suggest me how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved finally. In telnetd there are many calls where in which environment gets re-set. And startslave is the function wherein which tty gets created and login process is forked. so, did getpeername(0, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &fromlen) in startslave and added env vars before forking login proc. Now vars are available.